# iOS7 Maps App - How can I replicate the globe view?

Tags: ios, ios7, maps, mkmapview

I should show a globe map with MKMapView for a client and I can't replicate the thing.

Is that thing native or is somewhere in the documentation? Or it is only a special feature in the Maps App?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: As far as I figure out, this is not in public APi right now.

Comment: Maybe you could use WhirlyGlobe-Maply SDK http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/